# Sharing CPU over a network

Tags: windows, grid-computing

Recently I've been wondering if that's possible to create an application which would take some CPU from one computer and conduct it to another pc connected to the same network for example. I have 2 laptops and one is much worse than the other. When I'm playing a game the first laptop overheats quickly :P and I would like the better laptop to take some of the CPU, execute the calculations and return the results back so that the weaker laptop wouldn't overheat too quickly :P.
Is that possible to code in C/C++? With use of WinAPI or sth? Or maybe there is already an application which would enable me to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Not as simply as you're probably looking for, no. Some old games may be very well playable over Remote Desktop, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Still, there are some options, with a bit of tweaking, that can be used to play a game remotely, for example: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-1638643/tutorial-create-onlive-remote-streaming-setup.html

Comment: hmm that solves the problem partially but not completely. I would like to be able to play the game independently on both computers and not share the mouse, screen, keyboard... just the cpu ^^

Comment: @Savail: Well, I can imagine that you could solve that using a virtual server (Hyper-V or something similar), which would run two logical computers, but given that you apparently can't get a new computer, getting a Hyper-V machine might be just as impossible. Maybe there's free alternatives, but I have no idea. "Sharing" a CPU (and GPU!) is hard enough on one machine, and it gets harder over the network.